# Remove Dictionary from list when a condition is met with python

Tags: python

I have the following list:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Book1",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 30278752,
                "isbn": " 1594634025",
                "average_rating": " 3.92"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Book2",
        "details": [
            {
                "isbn": "  1501173219",
                "average_rating": "4.33 "
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to delete a whole dictionary when there is **no id** in it.How can i do this please?
I tried this solution:

```
final = filter(lambda x: x['id'] in details, var)
```

But this is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehensions and do something like:

```py
myList = [
    {
        "name": "Book1",
        "details": [
            {
                "id": 30278752,
                "isbn": " 1594634025",
                "average_rating": " 3.92"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Book2",
        "details": [
            {
                "isbn": "  1501173219",
                "average_rating": "4.33 "
            }
        ]
    }
]

[x for x in myList if "id" in x["details"][0]]
```

##### Output

```
[{'details': [{'average_rating': ' 3.92',
    'id': 30278752,
    'isbn': ' 1594634025'}],
  'name': 'Book1'}]
```